# Browsing history removal while IE running, IE index.dat clean up for Windows XP

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

There is an app for public access which uses IE8 on XP that should be left running and never (hopefully) restarted.
After client sessions, IE browsing history shall be cleaned.

It seems that after cleaning browser history (IE's Delete Browsing History) there still seem to be some cookies data left which can be seen by reopening a site that was not previously logged out. Also it can be seen by searching into index.dat files.

Is there a way to clean (set to zeros) / remove index.dat files while the system (including IE) is up and running?

It seems to be possible to close the opened file handles (with tool like OpenedFilesView) though they still seem no to be writable / removable.